# How can I generate some Python scripts based on different conditions nicely?

Tags: python, appearance

I want to generate some Python scripts based on different conditions. It means: I have a constant body of my Python scripts, which is exactly the same in all the different conditions, but due to the fact that I have several different conditions, there are some regions in those Python scripts that should be changed. Let's say this is my constant part, which is similar for all the conditions:

```
import numpy as np

variables = []

for i in range(100):
 variables.append(tempVariable)

print variables
```

And I have 4 different conditions, where `tempVariable` is calculated differently as:

Condition 1: `tempVariable = i`

Condition 2: `tempVariable = i**2`

Condition 3: `tempVariable = i**3`

Condition 4: `tempVariable = i + 4.34`

Note that I don't want to use `if` statement to switch over these four conditions cause these conditions are in fact different cases and are not related together. At the end, I want to have `variables` for these four different conditions and cases independently. My idea is that to put these four cases or conditions into a txt file and treat the constant part of the Python script as an another txt file and iterate over all these four conditions or cases and add the necessary part for calculating the `tempVariable` before appending it into `variables`. Of course, it looks pretty ugly and more importantly I want to ship it to other people to be able to use it. I appreciate if there is any more nice and generic approach to it. In my real application, I have 94 different conditions or cases, which would be really ugly, if I want to put them under some `if` or `elif` statements. Any suggestion or idea is appreciated.

Comment: So you want a base script, which you then add in some additional code depending on the use? Like a template?

Comment: It's not clear why you don't want to use an conditional statement here. That seems like exactly the right tool for the job. Or maybe a dictionary of functions?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Note that I have 94 different conditions in my real application, I don't want to create a long list of if statements to switch over them. It is pretty easy if I had 4 or 5 different conditions, but 94 is pretty high and would make appearance of the code pretty messy.

Comment: Actually now that I'm reading it more, it sounds like you just want some functions. The typical "recipe" for generalizing code using functions is to take the parts that are the same and put them in the body of a function, then take the parts that differ and make those parameters of the function.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer What are the conditions? Give a sample.

Comment: I would consider using single script with conditions provided during runtime e.g. you can parse parameters through ```argparse``` and direct to the proper loop accordingly

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes but again that "function" how would you switch over different conditions? Even in my real application different conditions use completely different for example numpy functionalities. For example case 1: use numpy.max but case 2: use numpy.min. How would you pass another functionality as a variable to another function?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Again, show example conditions. If the "conditions" are just checking equality against something, a dictionary of functions may be appropriate.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Those are example that I provided in the question but I don't want to take advantage of their simplicity cause I just simplified them for showing my problem. In fact in real application, different conditions have several different lines with completely different functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution, which is really better fit for cases that there are countless conditions (i.e. 1000 different conditions). In fact, I put all the **commands** in a text file that could be parsed and read automatically as:

`commands.txt`:

```
tempVariable = i
tempVariable = i**2
tempVariable = i**3
tempVariable = i + 4.34
```

Then, I read and execute them like this:

```
def Execute(command):
 variables = []

 for i in range(100):
  exec(command)
  variables.append(tempVariable)

 print variables

if __name__ == "__main__":
 conditions = open('commands.txt').read().split('\n')[:-1]
 map(Execute, conditions)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are always using a polynomial, you could have a list of the coefficients that is passed to your function.

For the conditions you have provided, an object like:

```
mylist = [[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[4.34,1,0,0]]
```

Then your `n`th condition line would just have to read:

```
Condition: tempVariable = mylist[n][0] + mylist[n][1]*i + mylist[n][2]*i**2 + mylist[n][3]*i**3
```

By building up a generalized condition you won't need multiple copies of this function

Comment: I like this. The only thing is, for large exponents, you will have large arrays with only a single none zero element. Maybe instead of listing all the coefficients, store the polynomial degree and the coefficient as a pair. Or if your coefficient is always 1, then just the degree.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to change conditions on run time but when executing the program:
You can add constant variables at the beginning of the file, or you can create a file like `parameters` and store all conditions and which one is active in that file.
Then import that file and take the active condition(parameter) and act as it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **lambdas**.

Here is an example to demonstrate the idea.

```
lambdas = [None]*4

lambdas[0] = lambda i : i

lambdas[1] = lambda i : i**2

lambdas[2] = lambda i : i**3

lambdas[3] = lambda i : i + 4.34


for i in range(0, 10):
    print( "=====  ", i )
    print( lambdas[0](i) )
    print( lambdas[1](i) )
    print( lambdas[2](i) )
    print( lambdas[3](i) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
variables = []
func_dict = {'linear': lambda x: x, 'squared': lambda x: x ** 2, 'cubed': lambda x: x ** 3}


def calculator(func, myArray):
    for i in range(10):
        myArray.append(func(i))


answers = {}
for func_name in func_dict:
    new_arr = []
    calculator(func_dict[func_name], new_arr)
    answers[func_name] = new_arr

print(answers)
```

The output:

```
{'linear': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'squared': [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], 'cubed': [0, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]}
```

With this, when you have a new function, all you need to do is add it to the function dict. Nothing else needs to be changed. It may be that you can simplify this further.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
def cond1(x):
    return x

def cond2(x):
    return x**2

def cond3(x):
    return x**3

def cond4(x):
    return x + 4.34

my_conds = (cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4)
variables = [list(map(cond, range(100))) for cond in my_conds]
```